# knockout js ensuring one value is larger than another

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following business requirement:

There are 2 textboxes where a user needs to input their current age and their retirement age. 
The retirement age needs to be greater than the current age so if a user inputs a retirement age that's less than the current age it should update the retirement age to the current age, and if a user inputs a current age that is greater than the retirement age then the retirement age must be set to the current age.

Is there an easy way to do this using knockout js? I'm assuming I'll need a computed observable for both fields with some kind of backing store?

Heres my starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/RVNHy/

js:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    this.currentAge= ko.observable(32);
    this.retirementAge = ko.observable(44);  
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel ());
```

html:

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>Current Age: <input data-bind='value: currentAge' /></p> 
    <p>Retirement Age: <input data-bind='value: retirementAge' /></p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that is what you want:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var age= ko.observable(32);
    var retAge = ko.observable(44); 

    self.currentAge = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return age();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            retAge(Math.max(value, retAge));
            age(value);
        },
        owner: this
    });
}
```

And do the same to create a computed observable for the retirement age.